# How to Receive Json array in Php from android studio and save it in mysql

Tags: php, android, json, http

I would like to like to receive the JSON array and save it to an SQLite database? The steps I have taken are as follows:

- I have created an SQLite database in Android Studio.
- I converted the SQLite database into a JSON array, when a button is clicked
- Through a Http request the array is sent

There are four columns.

```
try {

                // 1. create HttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( "http://192.168.1.7/sql.php");

//TotalRecord=jsonarray.toString();

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(TotalRecord);
                abc=true;

                // 6. set httpPost Entity
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

With those columns I would like to recieve the data inside them into the JSON array, Any way of achieving this in PHP?

Post Structure is :

```
            Cursor res = myDB.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("error", "nothing to disply");
                return;
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            //JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      while (res.moveToNext()) {// Converted whole sqlite database in Json
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                String id = "";
                String name = "";
                String surname = "";
                String marks = "";
                id = String.valueOf(stringBuffer.append(res.getString(0)));
                name = String.valueOf(stringBuffer.append(res.getString(1)));
                surname = String.valueOf(stringBuffer.append(res.getString(0)));
                marks = String.valueOf(stringBuffer.append(res.getString(0)));
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("ID", id);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("Name", name);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("SurName", surname);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("Marks", marks);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                TotalRecord = jsonArray.toString();
```

Comment: It's a very simple task. Please, tell us the structure of your POST request. What variable contains the JSON array?

Comment: i have edited my question , Now you can see  the Structure . Reply soon. Thnx

Comment: As far as I understand, you have a JSON string in TotalRecord variable. But I am not sure, whether it is passed in POST array with key `TotalRecord`. If it is just get your associated array with following php code: `$jsonObject = json_decode($_POST['TotalRecord']);`

Comment: i have associated "TotalRecord" .  
This Method "  $jsonObject = json_decode($_POST['TotalRecord']); "

Comment: i have associated "TotalRecord" to send it to computer. 
This Method "  $jsonObject = json_decode($_POST['TotalRecord']); " will receive JSON Array  ,but how to open that  $jsonObject  in in four variable ?

Comment: This is an associated array. Use syntax: `$jsonObject['ID']`, `$jsonObject['Name']` etc.